# unable to change secure_file_priv in my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have problems loading in a csv file, `secure_file_priv` is set to `NULL`, and that prevents me from reading in the csv file. I am trying to change `secure_file_priv` in my `my.cnf` file, but my changes don't go through.
mysql says:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

so I made a `my.cnf` file in `/etc`, but the changes don't go through. (I restarted mysql server in mac preferences window)

this is what my file looks like:

```
[mysqld]
wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
secure_file_priv=""
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

i edited my `my.cnf` file, restarted mysql server but when i use show variables like `secure_file_priv` it still says `NULL`, how can i alter the `secure_file_priv` option?

Comment: How did you start your server? Did you provide the parameter `--defaults-file`? You can probably see this with `ps aux | grep mysql`

Comment: i start my server with the mac system preferences menu, from there i can select the mysql server and stop and start it. using your command i can see `--defaults-file =` is provided, it doesn't have any value behind the `=` though, i don't know if that is needed?

Comment: Also check if any other config files mentioned have a different value of `secure_file_priv` as they will override what you have in `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: @mustaccio i checked all locations, i got `my.cnf` files in `/etc/` and `~/`, both are 100% the same, with same value for `secure_file_priv`

Comment: Change, say, the max_allowed_packet next to it -- to see if that conf file really is being used.

Comment: @RickJames changing that in both files does not make a difference, it says at:  67108864. I also tried changing max_allowed_packet in mysql in the terminal, but that also appears to not work (does not give an error though) 

`mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=16384;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';

| Variable_name      | Value    |

| max_allowed_packet | 67108864 |

1 row in set (0.01 sec)
`

Comment: @Mapijs - `SET GLOBAL ...` establishes the setting for _future_ logins (until the next restart).  `SHOW VARIABLES` looks at the "session" values, where were initialized to the global values when you logged in.

Comment: @Mapijs - I was suggesting changing that _in the conf file_ to see if it were propagating to the running system.  It won't get there until you restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know in Linux but in Windows 10/MySQL80 (`my.ini` instead of `my.cnf`) the option is spelled `secure-file-priv`  **and not** `secure_file_priv`. Do not forget to restart the service once the change is made.

I sadly lost one evening before finding my error. This is especially confusing as the SQL query to check the variable value is `SELECT @@secure_file_priv`.